# How to edit the Main Menu Labels in Symfony 5, EasyAdmin 4?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I am using Symfony **EasyAdmin 4** and couldn't figure out how to change the main menu's entities' labels. They default to their entities' name.

This seems easily achievable with **EasyAdmin 2.x**, as the [old docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/2.x/tutorials/i18n.html#translate-the-main-menu-labels) show. But none of the files mentioned there (`translations/messages.xx.yaml`,`config/packages/easy_admin.yaml`) is still in use in [EasyAdmin 4.x](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/index.html).

**So, how to edit the Main Menu Labels in EasyAdmin?**

Comment: I wanted to remove this, but thought that juniors starting with Symfony might need it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We don't need any of those files in `EasyAdmin 4`:

This can be achieved by simply implementing `setEntityLabelInSingular` and `setEntityLabelInPlural` methods inside the `configureCrud` method inside the concerned crud controller:

```
class YourCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{     
    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
         {
             return $crud
                 ->setEntityLabelInSingular('Your own label')
                 ->setEntityLabelInPlural('Your own labels')
                 ...
                 ;
          }
...
}
```

*Don't forget the* : `use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;`

---

More here: [Symfony: The Fast Track](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/9-backend.html)

Comment: Please share more details. How does this help to **translate** the labels?

Comment: You are right it doesn't **translate** it, but  rather **changes** the labels.
I edited the question and the answer 